# ¨How set the title to the panel dynamically by getting the panel using its id in inExt.getCmp('myPanelID'), What are the properties to set title

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a Ext panel and I want to set the Title of the panel from some variable .

I have the `id` of the panel and I need to set the title of the panel from it.

I am looking for some thing like this,

`Ext.getCmp('myPanel').setTitle();` like atribute

```
Ext.define('Myapplication.view.Contacts', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.Contacts',
    id: 'myPanelID',
    ----
    -----
    ------
    -----

    listeners: [
        {
           fn: 'initComponent',
           event: 'initialize'
        }
    ]
},
initComponent: function(component, options, wstitle) {
    Ext.getCmp('myPanelID').header.title = ('Title of panel'); //Not working
    Ext.getCmp('myPanelID').setTitle= ('Title of panel'); //Not working
}
```

alway got an error:

**TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ext.getCmp('myPanel').setTitle')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ext.getCmp('myPanelID').setTitle` is a function.

So...

`Ext.getCmp('myPanelID').setTitle('Title of panel');`

Is what you are looking for

Comment: in this case also got an error TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ext.getCmp('myPanel').setTitle')

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.Panel` is a instead of `Ext.Container` so, is a container and not is an object. If you want change someone like **`title`** you can try something like this,

```
Ext.define('Myapplication.view.Contacts', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.Contacts',
    id: 'myPanelID',
    ...

    html: '<div>Your Title</div>',
    ...

    initComponent: function(component, options, wstitle) {
        Ext.getCmp('myPanelID').setHtml('<div>Another Title</div>');
    }
})
```

**Hope these helps. :)**

Answer (score 0):

you got a syntax error. You write

```
Ext.getCmp('myPanelID').setTitle= ('Title of panel'); //Not working
```

remove the = char

```
Ext.getCmp('myPanelID').setTitle('Title of panel'); //Works like a charm
```

cheers, Oleg